# Error in adding ISO template to Cloudstack

Tags: cloudstack

I'm trying to add an ISO template to Cloudstack so that I can create instances, and I'm sure I've registered the ISO correctly.

Currently, it looks like this:

[image].

What it should look like is this, with the option to edit, download, delete etc.

[image]

Is it a UI error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have added iso as template.
You need to choose "upload iso" option and register it as iso, then it should work fine.

Comment: By upload, did you mean download? But either way, both option can't be done. I've ran the diagnostics and found the problem, the ssvm can't connect to the outside world. Might be an ACL or my network setup. I still haven't figured it out but it seems to be a common problem

Comment: If your ssvm is unable to ping the iso server (from where you are trying to download iso) then edit the global settings, and add the network id of the iso server in "secstorage.allowed.internal.sites"  and then restart CSM service...

for example:
if the download link is http://x.x.x.x/test.iso
add x.x.x.x/XX i.e  IP-ADDR/SUBNET

This will add route to your iso server inside the ssvm and then you should be able to ping that network....